# Small help text relative to input field

Tags: html, css, html-input

I need to put a small help text directly under a text input field, and if this field is indented (e.g. by a radio button as in my example), the help text should be indented too.

An example of what I'm trying is here:

```css
#enteramt {
  width: 150px;
  display: inline;
}

#passwordHelpBlock {
  font-size: x-small;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<p class="lead">
  <input id="val_200" name="amount_sel" type="radio" value="200">
  <label for="val_200"> EUR 200,00</label>
  <br/>
  <input id="val_other" name="amount_sel" type="radio" value="other">
  <label for="val_other"> EUR
    <input class="inputdefault" id="enteramt" name="amount" type="text" value="" placeholder="z.B. 2,00">
  </label>
  <small id="passwordHelpBlock" class="form-text text-muted">Min. EUR 2,00</small>
</p>
```

Also see in Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mheumann/wkLdjdcL/

I want it to look like this:

[image: Preview of what it should look like]

I know I could use margin-left to move it over, but the same box may also appear without the radio button, so the margin would vary.

Is there any way to bind the "small" tag to the "input" tag so it will always appear aligned directly underneath?

EDIT: Removed references to Bootstrap, since the code snippet doesn't contain any.

Comment: How about just adding some padding to the `.text-muted` selector?  `padding-left: 70px` ?

Comment: @BrandonElder: That would not be flexible enough, as I mentioned, there are cases where the same label and input field are displayed without a radio button, so the padding would have to be adjusted...

Comment: yeah, I figured.  I'm actually very curious about the solution for this.

Comment: Me too. I tried a lot of combinations inserting divs at various places but couldn't find anything that worked.

Comment: Where is the bootstrap CSS in all this? You tagged it *and* included it in your title, but there's none here.

Comment: You're right, @miken32. I use bootstrap in this project, but the posted code doesn't actually have any. I'll remove the references to it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can wrap the input and the help text inside a `<span>` and make it an `inline-block`

**see code snippet:**

```css
#enteramt {
  width: 150px;
  display: inline;
}

#passwordHelpBlock {
  font-size: x-small;
  display: block;
}

.input-help {
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<p class="lead">
  <input id="val_200" name="amount_sel" type="radio" value="200">
  <label for="val_200"> EUR 200,00</label>
  <br/>
  <input id="val_other" name="amount_sel" type="radio" value="other">
  <label for="val_other"> EUR
    <span class="input-help">
      <input class="inputdefault" id="enteramt" name="amount" type="text" value="" placeholder="z.B. 2,00">
      <small id="passwordHelpBlock" class="form-text text-muted">Min. EUR 2,00</small>
    </span>
  </label>
</p>
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for!! Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

```css
#enteramt {
  width: 150px;
  display: inline;
}

#passwordHelpBlock {
  font-size: x-small;
  display: block;
}

.p-l-none{
  padding-left:0px !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <input id="val_200" name="amount_sel" type="radio" value="200">
  <label for="val_200"> EUR 200,00</label>
  
  </div>
</div>


<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
   <input id="val_other" name="amount_sel" type="radio" value="other">
   EUR   
    
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-5 p-l-none">
  <input class="inputdefault" id="enteramt" name="amount" type="text" value="" placeholder="z.B. 2,00" class="form-control">
    <small id="passwordHelpBlock" class="form-text text-muted">Min. EUR 2,00</small>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wkLdjdcL/3/)

Is this the same that you are looking for?
Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, your solution is not bad but it reformats my form so I prefer the one by @chiller.

Comment: That's fine. You got your solution. :)

Answer (score 0):

How about using [Adjacent sibling selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors)?
Here the padding will be applied only on `.text-muted` which is preceded by an input of type radio and a label. (just to match your current html)
If there is no radio button / label, then padding will not apply.

```css
#enteramt {
  width: 150px;
  display: inline;
}

#passwordHelpBlock {
  font-size: x-small;
  display: block;
}

input[type=radio] + label + .text-muted {
  padding-left: 60px;
}
```

```html
<p class="lead">
  <input id="val_200" name="amount_sel" type="radio" value="200">
  <label for="val_200"> EUR 200,00</label>
  <br/>
  <input id="val_other" name="amount_sel" type="radio" value="other">
  <label for="val_other"> EUR
    <input class="inputdefault" id="enteramt" name="amount" type="text" value="" placeholder="z.B. 2,00">
  </label>
  <small id="passwordHelpBlock" class="form-text text-muted">Min. EUR 2,00</small>
</p>
```

Comment: Vertical alignment using the padding-left property is an unreliable and non-universal solution.

Comment: I think it's horizontal in this case, @GlebKemarsky. I still like this suggestion because I didn't know you could even do this kind of thing in CSS. Maybe it'll come in handy some time.